# Initializing a generic field from a generic List

Tags: dart

My class

```
class Tuple<E extends num> {
  final E _a;
  final E _b;
  final E _c;

  const Tuple(this._a, this._b, this._c);

  Tuple.fromList(List<E> list)
      : _a = list.asMap().containsKey(0) ? list[0] : 0 , // The initializer type 'num' can't be assigned to the field type 'E'.
        _b = list.asMap().containsKey(1) ? list[1] : 0 as E,
        _c = list.asMap().containsKey(2) ? list[2] : 0 as E;

  E get first => _a;
  E get second => _b;
  E get third => _c;

// adding and subtracting a tuple into another tuple
  Tuple operator +(Tuple other) =>
      Tuple(_a + other._a, _b + other._b, _c + other._c);

  Tuple operator -(Tuple other) =>
      Tuple(_a - other._a, _b - other._b, _c - other._c);

  @override
  String toString() => 'Tuple(first: $first, second: $_b, third: $_c)';
}
```

Why I am getting this error "The initializer type 'num' can't be assigned to the field type 'E'."

Even though

```
final E _a; // restricted as <E extends num>
```

But If I do the casting as the following the error goes away

```
0 as E
```

Your detailed answer is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because even though `E` is guaranteed to be a compatible type of `num`, it's not guaranteed to be a compatible type of `int`.

Imagine if your `Tuple` was initialized where `E` was `double`. Your initializer would basically be doing:

```dart
double e = 0 as int;
```

To hopefully make it clearer, let's use types `Animal`, `Dog`, and `Cat`, where `Dog` and `Cat` both extend `Animal`:

```dart
class Tuple<E extends Animal> {
  // ...

  Tuple.fromList(List<E> list)
      : _a = list.asMap().containsKey(0) ? list[0] : Dog(),
        _b = list.asMap().containsKey(1) ? list[1] : Dog(),
        _c = list.asMap().containsKey(2) ? list[2] : Dog();
}
```

If someone tried to do `Tuple<Cat>.fromList(...)`, there would obviously be a problem because your initializer is now trying to populate a `Tuple<Cat>` with a bunch of dogs.

---

As an aside, why are you using `list.asMap().containsKey(...)`? That's an incredibly wasteful practice with no positives. Why not just use `list.length >= ...`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and I really appreciate your detailed explanation.